# Why isn't Javascript recognising variable in event listener

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, addeventlistener

Here is my code for a simple video player with buttons.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var playButton = document.querySelector(".playbtn");
var stopButton = document.querySelector(".stopbtn");

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    vid.play();
})

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    vid.pause();
})
```

The video is playing on loop but when I tried to add these event listeners I get the error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Whats wrong with my variables, why aren't they being recognized?

Comment: Probably because you are reading the buttons before they are rendered to the page.

Comment: Pass `playButton`, etc. to `console.log()` and see if the result is what you expect. Make sure the DOM is loaded before you run this code.

Comment: Oh bugger! The one time I don't add a document.ready function !!! (THANKS)